# Self hosted image collaboration / proof system

Tags: open-source, images, collaboration

Are there any free/open source projects for self-hosted image collaboration / proofing?

I work with many clients and I need a system that will allow for each client to have their own account where they can upload typesets / images, etc. Then they notify me of their upload, so I can review their requirements and start their design.

Once the design is completed, I need to upload it back to their account, have the system notify them of the upload, and then let them review the proof and make any notes if needed.

The simpler the system the better - it doesn't need to be fancy or bloated, just functional.

Additional Info:

- The system will need to run on a remote dedicated server running Ubuntu 14.04 server. All the basic goodies are available on the server
- Apache, MySQL, PHP5.5, etc. I currently host a few other websites on the server, most Joomla or WordPress based.
- Clients should be able to visit my website, log in and then access the interface to manage their typesets.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too specific and you'll have to use your text editor and programming knowledge to make that yourself.

Comment: A document management system can probably do what you need, but I can't make a specific recommendation.

Comment: Thank you, Christian Ciupitu. I had been thinking of taking a simple forum system and modifying it. A document management system may be a good way to go as well. I'll do some searching and see if I can find a system that would provide a good base framework to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/)? Here is a quote from it:

> Access your data from all your devices, on an open platform you can extend and modify.

The way I often introduce OwnCloud to somebody new to it is like "*Think of it as your 'private' version of Dropbox, somewhere in the cloud. Where 'you' set the terms and conditions for anybody you authorize to use it ... And free of charge, except of course the cost to implement and run it on 'your' server. Did I mention syncing with phones, tables, etc, instead of using iCloud (and its terms and conditions ...)?*".

There are also some [questions about Owncloud around here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=owncloud%20is%3Aq) that may be worth exploring ...

Our own experience about Owncloud is like so:

- a collegae of mine introduced it to me at first (and is using it already for quite a while).
- We're now implementing it on a new Linux server for one of our customers (with like 10 employees / subcontractors).
- Next we'll to start using it on a Linux server for our own use.
- Finally we'll roll it out to our Smalll Business customers with similar needs (cloud based, managed by us).

PS: Looks like creating tag [owncloud](/questions/tagged/owncloud) might make sense also ... (to get those questions tagged with it ...

Comment: Very interesting... I haven't seen nor heard of it before. I'll look into it and see what all it offers and how I maybe able to get it to fit the need. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Thx for your first impression feedback ... yes it is veeeeeeery interesting. Just so you know: "I" am in no way affiliated with it. But interested in any feedback you might have about it (to add it to my "portfolio" of impressions I heard from others). Maybe some day this answer becomes a candidate for being marked as "accepted" answer?

Comment: Thanks again, Pierre. I think that if your needs are pretty basic then Owncloud does the job and is by far the quickest solution.